# Is it possible to configure the same VMs behind more than one App Gateway in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

Is it possible to configure the same VMs behind more than one App Gateway in Azure. I have a set of VMs which are a part of the backend pool for an application gateway. I want the add the same VMs to the back end pool for another application gateway. Is that possible. I checked documentation and could not find any reference to the above.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Yes, it's possible. You can configure the same VMs behind more than one App Gateway in Azure. Additional, you can also configure the same VMs in the same App Gateway more than one time.

Comment: i would think the same